# How to convert data values of an excel file

Tags: python

[This is my excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pvt2c.jpg)

```
column_list = []
df_column = pd.read_excel(r'data/health-insurance.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1').columns
for i in df_column:
    column_list.append(i)
converter = {col: str for col in column_list} 
df_actual = pd.read_excel('data/health-insurance.xlsx', converters=converter)
df_actual['New York City','Estimate'][0]
```

I have tried with lambda, astype, to_numeric functions but couldn't succeed.

Comment: check the indentation in your code. please read indentation in python.

Comment: Which editor you are using? Try replacing `tab` by `4 spaces`. recomended in PEP8 standerds https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces

Comment: this seems to be an indentation error. please check your code before submitting a question like this

Comment: What's your question? The traceback says it all, doesn't it? Your `df` is a pandas dataframe, and as such it does not have an attribute `parse`. You could for example do `df.head()`, `df.describe()` or `df.info()`. What do you try to achieve with `df.parse('Sheet1')`?

Comment: I want to import excel file,convert data values into integer and pass the data frame through a function. Primarily i have done this:- 
file = pd.read_excel(r'data/health-insurance.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
df=file.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
df['New York City','Estimate'][0]
But couldn't get any success

Answer (score 1):

the DataFrame object does not have a 'parse' function according to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html.

---

You could read each row into an array, and then load the array into the file object.

Comment: I am trying to convert data values from string to integer. I have tried lambda,astype,to_numeric functions but not getting any result. Can you please help me?
file = pd.read_excel(r'data/health-insurance.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
df=file.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
df['New York City','Estimate'][0]

Comment: Python data type conversion documentation is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html   scroll down to integer casting.  I did the following example change a string of "1" to int of 1 successfully.
***
x="1"
x=int(x)
print(x)
***
output:
1